# Connecting two Docker Containers Flask to PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask

I am new to docker so this may be a silly question. I have one docker container containing a PostGIS database and another containing a Flask App. When running the Flask app locally I have no problems connecting to the database, running migrations etc. But when I launch the Flask app into its own container, any connection results in an error like this

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The error suggests the database container isn't accepting incoming traffic, but this is confusing because it does work when the incoming traffic is not from another container.

The way I run the database is by simply pulling the PostGIS image down

```
docker run \
        --name some-postgis \
        --publish 5432:5432 \
        --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD='password' \
        --env POSTGRES_DB='my-database' \
        -d postgis/postgis
```

The Dockerfile for the Flask app looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster

RUN mkdir /build /app

WORKDIR /build

COPY . /build/
COPY requirements/base.txt /build/requirements/base.txt
COPY alembic.ini /build/
COPY source_files/ /build/source_files/
COPY alembic/ /build/alembic/


RUN python3 -m pip install \
    --target /app \
    --requirement ./requirements/base.txt

ENV PORT 5000
ENV PATH "/app/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
EXPOSE ${PORT}

RUN groupadd --gid 999 user && \
    useradd --system \
        --uid 999 \
        --gid user \
        user

USER user:user

ENV FLASK_ENV=development
ENV FLASK_APP=src/main.py
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I have seen lots about docker compose and networks, but I have worked with prepared containers where an API is in 1 and database in another without doing that and haven't had problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the code that tells the flask application the address of the database?

It looks to me like flask is trying to connect to localhost:5432, which will work fine in local mode as the database is accessible on localhost:5432 (docker is exposing to the host machine), but when running in a container, flask is its own host and cannot access host machine services via localhost.

Providing the above is correct, there is a couple of different ways to do it:

- Access host machine ports (and therefore exposed ports from other containers) with "host.docker.internal:5432" instead of "localhost:5432" in flask.
- Use docker compose or similar, name the database container e.g. postgis, and connect to "postgis:5432"
- Create a docker network instead https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: yes, I think you are exactly right. I had hardcoded localhost in the application. When I swapped that for the IP the database container was running on then I was able to connect. The only problem that leaves me with is that it'll break when that IP address changes. I will have a look at docker networks and docker compose. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: I prefer docker compose as you can create and tear down entire self-contained networks with single commands and it generally handles all the networking for you, you just have to use container names to address each other (e.g. make a docker-compose.yml file, call the database "db", give the flask microservice an environmental variable "DB_HOST=db", in flask where it asks for database address, have it pick up the variable with something like os.getenv("DB_HOST")). Hope that helps.